# Infinite assignement of a row for each user mysql

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

I have an array like the following :

```
$staffs = array("john","mark","belly","rick", "tom", "harry");
```

I have a mysql table called candidates :

```
Id  name       email                    date_signup   staff
1   candidat1  candidat1@candidat1.com  2016/09/01
2   candidat2  candidat2@candidat2.com  2021/05/22
3   candidat3  candidat3@candidat2.com  2021/05/22
4   candidat4  candidat4@candidat2.com  2021/05/22
5   candidat5  candidat5@candidat2.com  2021/05/22
6   candidat6  candidat6@candidat2.com  2021/05/22
7   candidat7  candidat7@candidat2.com  2021/05/22
8   candidat8  candidat8@candidat2.com  2021/05/22
9   candidat9  candidat9@candidat9.com  2021/05/22
10  candidat10 candidat10@candidat10.com 2021/05/22
```

How can I update candidates table for each staff in my staffs array

My final output I trying to achieve is except its for 6's of staffs:

```
    Id  name       email                    date_signup  staff
    1   candidat1  candidat1@candidat1.com  2016/09/01   john
    2   candidat2  candidat2@candidat2.com  2021/05/22   mark
    3   candidat3  candidat3@candidat2.com  2021/05/22   belly
    4   candidat4  candidat4@candidat2.com  2021/05/22   rick
    5   candidat5  candidat5@candidat2.com  2021/05/22   tom
    6   candidat6  candidat6@candidat2.com  2021/05/22   harry
    7   candidat7  candidat7@candidat2.com  2021/05/22   john
    8   candidat8  candidat8@candidat2.com  2021/05/22   mark
    9   candidat9  candidat9@candidat9.com  2021/05/22   belly
    10  candidat10 candidat10@candidat10.com 2021/05/22   rick
.....
```

Some code that I start with :

```
$candidat = "INSERT INTO `candidates`(`name`,`email`,date_sign_up) VALUES ('$name','$email','$date_signup') ";
mysqli_query($con, $candidat );
    
$id_can = mysqli_insert_id($con);
    
    $Query = "SELECT * from candidates WHERE ORDER BY id DESC limit 0,1";
    $Records = mysqli_query($con, $Query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($Records );
    $user_st = $row['status_par'];
    if($user_st == 'john'){
    $staff= 'mark';
    }
    if($user_st == 'mark'){
    $staff= 'belly';
    }....
    
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE candidates SET staff= '$staff' where id='$id_can' ");
```

I read about select from candidates and use if condition for every staff or just using foreach key value loop any help much appreciated.

Comment: What MySQL version you have?

Comment: Mysql version is the 5.6

Comment: I can upgrade to the latest version if needed !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean you can do this by single query:

```
update `candidates`
join (
    select 1 as id, 'John' as name union
    select 2, 'Bruce'
) staff  on mod(candidates.id, 2)+1 = staff.id -- where 2 is count of staff
set candidates.staff = staff.name, candidates.date_signup = curdate();
```

[Test SQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=38bc71a3003415867aca78dc97a06bb3&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

[MySQL 8.0 solution](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=&sqlses=0eb74b360cf4075b10624f44cd2eb25c&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80):

```
with staff (id, name) as (
    select 1, 'John' union
    select 2, 'Bruce'
) update staff
join `candidates` c on mod(c.id, 2)+1 = staff.id -- where 2 is count of staff
set c.staff = staff.name, date_signup = curdate();

select * from candidates;
```

By prefer way is store staff in separate SQL table that give ability to mere complicate updates

Clear PHP solution:

```
<?php
$staffs = array("john","mark","belly","rick", "tom", "harry"); 

$query = "UPDATE candidates SET staff = ?, date_signup = CURDATE() WHERE mod(id, ?) = ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);

foreach($staffs as $i=>$name) {
    $staff_count = count($staffs);
    $stmt->execute([$name, $staff_count, $i]);
}
```

[PHP & MySQL online sandbox](https://phpize.online/?phpses=108490fe7e348e1071fe31e951b889da&sqlses=806d2935cfee3a410d012eeb1f66e5a0&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: lot of Thanks to you, I test it and I give you a feed <3

Comment: It's work, thanks Slava (y) tou are a genious !!